# How to share types generated from an ASMX service across WCF and Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, web-services

I've got a WCF service that sits as a middle tier between a client and an ASMX service. I've extracted the classes from the ASMX service and wrapped them in a separate dataContract dll using SVCUtil to generate the code. I've then added a reference to the shared DLL from a Winforms client and the WCF service.

The winforms client populates a type in the shared data contract dll and passes it to the WCF service but when the WCF service receives the type, it's null.

Are there additional steps I would need to take to wrap these ASMX types successfully in a shared assembly?

Comment: I never use them if I own both halves of the service.  This is only useful when you don't own the service, so you can automatically generate types that don't exist or that you don't have access to via some service SDK.  I usually just put the models that get pushed from the service side of the service in a shared DLL that the client then can reference and use when deserializing responses.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems with generated proxies and have total control over invoking service methods use shared (client) lib WCF contracts and create your own proxy class. See, for example, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/90804/Using-WCF-without-a-generated-proxy-by-using-Chann?msg=4174377#xx4174377xx) and [more](http://diegworld.blogspot.ru/2009/12/fancy-proxy-having-fun-with-wcf.html) for details.